# Declaring multiple ranges with changing integer n

Tags: excel, vba

My worksheet has multiple tables/listobjects. I am trying to select one table at a time (in successive view order not by table number, as there may be tables that were inserted in between already existing tables at some point). The tables are to be selected, converted to a range, then that range to be declared/set for future use. I cannot figure out how to do so because ranges have to be declared with a constant and not a variable. Here is my code thus far:

```
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Dim n As Integer
n = 1
Dim tableName As String
Dim SelectedCell As Range

For Each c In Range("B6:B" & LastRow)
    If c.Text = "Column1" Then
        c.Activate
        Set SelectedCell = ActiveCell
        tableName = SelectedCell.ListObject.Name
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Unlist
        Dim rng(n) As Range
        Set rng(n) = Selection
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReDim` is what you need (and also `Preserve` to not delete stored parameters). Also for doing it, it needs to be `Variant` which should be no problem here:

```
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim n As Integer, rng() As Variant
ReDim rng(1 To 1)
n = 1
Dim tableName As String
Dim SelectedCell As Range

For Each c In Range("B6:B" & LastRow)
  If c.Text = "Column1" Then
    c.Activate
    Set SelectedCell = ActiveCell
    tableName = SelectedCell.ListObject.Name
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Unlist
    ReDim Preserve rng(1 To n)
    Set rng(n) = Selection
    n = n + 1
  End If
Next
```